# Modifications to nested array elements do not stick

Tags: php

I am either working through the fatigue barrier or else I have a serious gap in my understanding of PHP.  Here is what I need to do

- I have an array (*A*) of arrays (*a*)
- I need to iterate through the outer array and
- for each of the inner arrays I need to add a new element, which in turn is an array
- this is the sort of code I churn out many times a day and I had expected little trouble with it.  However, much to my surprise whilst I can modify *a* I cannot make those modifications stick and appear in *A*

Here is the code

```
function fillRouteNames($routes,$export)
{
 for($i=0;$i < count($routes);$i++) 
 {
  $route = $routes[$i];
  trigger_error(gettype($route));//shows Array, as expected
  $disps = $route['d'];
  $nd = array();
  foreach($disps as $disp) $nd[] = fxnName($disp,$export);
  //now I have the new element I want to add
 $route['nd'] = $nd;
 trigger_error(json_encode($route));
 /as expected the output shows the new element, nd
}   
trigger_error(json_encode($routes));
//but now it is gone - it is like I never did $oute['nd'] = $nd
```

}

There must be something blindingly obvious here that is wrong but I have been unable to figure it out.  I hope that someone here will spot the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because `$route` is a copy of inner array. You need to add a reference or use direct index `$routes[$i]`. Something like this:

```
function fillRouteNames($routes,$export)
{
    for($i=0;$i < count($routes);$i++) 
    {
        $route = &$routes[$i];// add a reference

        trigger_error(gettype($route));

        $disps = $route['d'];
        $nd = array();
        foreach($disps as $disp) $nd[] = fxnName($disp,$export);

        $routes[$i]['nd'] = $nd;// OR use an index

        trigger_error(json_encode($route));
    }   
    trigger_error(json_encode($routes));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP arrays are assigned by value, not by reference. This means when the copy is modified, the change doesn't affect the original. `$route` and `$routes[$i]` are different arrays.

A possible solution is to copy `$route` back over `$routes[$i]` after you update it:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($routes); $i ++) {
    // Copy $routes[$i] into $routes for quick access and shorter code
    $route = $routes[$i];

    // Update $route as needed
    $route['nd'] = $nd;
    // ... more updates ...

    // Copy $route back over $routes[$i]
    $routes[$i] = $route;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect summary of the problem! Though I am afraid it does not quite provide a solution.

Comment: Added a possible solution to the problem. There are also other solutions: use references as describe in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35229858/4265352) (the references can make the code break in more unexpected ways), put the values of `$route` (updated or not) into a new array (and discard the original array after the loop), use objects instead of arrays etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing

```
function fillRouteNames($routes,$export)
{
 for($i=0;$i < count($routes);$i++) 
 {
  $disps = $routes[$i]['d'];
  $nd = array();
  foreach($disps as $disp) $nd[] = fxnName($disp,$export);
  $routes[$i]['nd'] = $nd;
 }  
 return $routes;
}
```

This simply avoids creating a local copy of the nested array element which circumvents the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't the last line be trigger_error(json_encode($route));